# Query XML with LINQ to return child elements that are different

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Consider the following two XML documents..

**Original**

```
<Stock>
   <Vehicle id="123456">
      <Name>Ford Ka</Name>
      <Images>
         <Image Id="111111" Url="http://somewhere.com/GetImage.aspx?ImageId=111111" LastModified="2016-05-12 13:09:00"/>
         <Image Id="222222" Url="http://somewhere.com/GetImage.aspx?ImageId=222222" LastModified="2016-05-12 13:09:00"/>
      </Images>
   </Vehicle>
</Stock>
```

**New**

```
<Stock>
   <Vehicle id="123456">
      <Name>Ford Ka</Name>
      <Images>
         <Image Id="111111" Url="http://somewhere.com/GetImage.aspx?ImageId=111111" LastModified="2016-05-12 13:09:00"/>
         <Image Id="222222" Url="http://somewhere.com/GetImage.aspx?ImageId=222222" LastModified="2016-05-13 09:00:00"/>
         <Image Id="333333" Url="http://somewhere.com/GetImage.aspx?ImageId=333333" LastModified="2016-05-12 13:09:00"/>
      </Images>
   </Vehicle>
</Stock>
```

So the differences between them are...

1. New XML `Image Id="222222"` has changed `LastModified` value.
2. New XML contains a new `<Image>` with `id="333333"`.

How can I use LINQ to return an `XDocument` that contains the `<Vehicle id>` and each `<Image>` where the `<Image id>` value in the new XML is not in the original XML (difference 2) OR the `<Image id>` IS in the original XML BUT any of the `<Image>` attribute values are different to those that in the original XML for the same Image (difference 1)?

The resulting `XDocument` should look something like this...

```
<Stock>
   <Vehicle id="123456">
      <Images>
         <Image Id="222222" Url="http://somewhere.com/GetImage.aspx?ImageId=222222" LastModified="2016-05-13 09:00:00"/>
         <Image Id="333333" Url="http://somewhere.com/GetImage.aspx?ImageId=333333" LastModified="2016-05-12 13:09:00"/>
      </Images>
   </Vehicle>
</Stock>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1] join old and new vehicles by `id` attribute

2] find new or modified `Image`s, comparing them by their string representation

3] select `Image`s into a new `Vehicle` element

4] built resulting `Stock` from `Vehicle` elements

```
var diff = from newVehicle in newXml.Descendants("Vehicle")
           join oldVehicle in oldXml.Descendants("Vehicle")
           on     newVehicle.Attribute("id").Value 
           equals oldVehicle.Attribute("id").Value 

           select new XElement("Vehicle", newVehicle.Attribute("id"),
                                new XElement("Images",
                                         newVehicle.Descendants("Image")
                                                   .Where(i=>!oldVehicle.Descendants("Image")
                                                                       .Any(iold=>iold.ToString() == i.ToString())
                                                          )
                                             )
                               );

var stock = new XElement("Stock", diff);
```